# JPA @OneToOne mapping with separate @Column definition

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have the following JPA entity relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Hardware {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;

 @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE } )
  protected HardwareStatus status;
}

@Entity
public class HardwareStatus {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable=false)
  protected Hardware parent;

  @Column(name="product_status", nullable=false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  protected ProductStatus productStatus;

  // .. lots of other fields
}
```

HardwareStatus records are calculated once a day around midnight and contain statistical information about that hardware.  Most of it is fine to get lazily.  However, I would like to have one of the fields (productStatus) available to me in the Hardware entity without loading the whole HardwareStatus object.  Is it possible to have something like:

```
@Entity
public class Hardware {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;

 @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE } )
  protected HardwareStatus status;

  @Column(name="product_status", nullable=false)
  // Some sort of JPA @Attribute to map to the HardwareStatus table to load just this field eagerly?
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  protected ProductStatus productStatus;
}
```

Thanks in advance